# Re-connect to corporate firewall

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, firewall, internet-connection

When I power on my PC, the default internet browser open the page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=219472&clcid=0x409 then I have to enter my credentials to access internet.

Every time, I am disconnected from internet (and only internet, the LAN is working well), I can't verify that internet was lost unless I went to browser to verify.

Is there a method to detect if internet connection was lost and log in to the firewall automatically?

Comment: When you use the term "corporate firewall" are you talking about a VPN or something else?

Comment: @Ramhound: Not using VPN.